# Неожиданное смещение элементов при ручной вёрстке

Tags: ios, swift

В `UITabvleViewController` использую вёрстку на фреймах, то есть располагаю все графические элементы с помощью кода. `UITabvleViewController` находится внутри `NavigationController`. При нажатии кнопки открывается `UIViewController`, котором есть `TextView`.

Если в этот `TextView` ввести что-нибудь, а потом вернуться назад к таблице, почти все элементы съезжают в точку 0. Не понимаю, почему так происходит. Ни один из написанных мной методов не срабатывает при этом, то есть перестроения не должно быть.

Есть идеи, как можно исправить проблему? И что послужило причиной этой проблемы?
[image: Так всё выглядит в нормальном режиме]

[image: А здесь видна проблема]

Comment: Выложите в вопрос ваш код, а так же графические образцы ошибки.

Comment: На фреймах с помощью кода в эпоху autolayout?

Comment: @ВикторМишустин код очень большой, поэтому лучше выложу ссылку на [gist](https://gist.github.com/KirillovE/b14d83115985f328c295f82e6b0f823d)

Comment: @Son'kaV да, такой вариант быстрее работает при большом количестве элементов на экране

Answer (score 0):

По коду:

```
[avatar, authorName, newsText, numberOfViews, numberOfReposts, numberOfComments, numberOfLikes, date, attachedImage].forEach { $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false }
```

не требуется, т.к. элементы добавлены в `Interface Builder`.

По проблеме, судя по тому что показано - попробуйте в `cellForRow` ячейке прописать:

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

P.S. Ну и насчет быстрее работает - сомнительно, если только не в `background` потоке фреймы обсчитывать, как в [LayoutKit](http://layoutkit.org/). Просто нужно попроще `constraints` делать, а не трехэтажные зависимости одной от другой.

Comment: Сначала заработало, но как-то странно, при переходе таблица сдвигалась вниз на несколько ячеек. Потом вообще работать перестало. Пересобирал несколько раз, но уже не работало

Comment: @ЕвгенийКириллов проект с этой проблемой можете приложить?

Comment: конечно, вот [ссылка](https://github.com/KirillovE/newVK)